# UK Polygon Property Boundaries and Addresses

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I am working on a project where i require the mapping of many UK property boundaries individually. Rather than going through each property and manually creating a polygon for its boundary, I was hoping to obtain a layer that connects the property address to the property boundary and automatically produces the polygon. Do you know if such a layer exists or is this achievable to create?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to purchase (or work for an organisation that has purchased) [Ordnance Survey's MasterMap](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/mastermap-products.html) topographic area data for your area of interest.

You may also be able to buy the same information from the [Land Registry](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/mapsearch) but I've never tried that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I previously checked with the Ordnance Survey and the information they have on addresses is restricted to a single grid reference and not the property boundary. I am not sure if it would be possible create automatic polygons connected to the address from this information as it is not linked to the property boundary in any way.

Comment: MasterMap does have the buildings and you need to join the AddressPoint PAF file both are an expensive product.

Comment: Thanks! i've had a look at MasterMap and got the following response "OS MasterMap Topography Layer, on a one-year contract covering Great Britain, for use on 101 or more terminals, costs £4,581,000." Unfortunately i have had a look at my bank account and sadly don't have a spare £4.5million per year haha. Is there any possible way of creating such a layer from OpenSource data layers and combining them?

Answer (score 1):

if it's in England and Wales, [The INSPIRE index polygons](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/inspire-index-polygons-spatial-data) are available as open data in GML format from HM Land Registry.

However, it doesn't appear that the unique identifiers for each property's boundary is tied  to a postal address in any way.

Pretty sure there is no similar data for Scotland (who have their own Land Registry), not sure about Northern Ireland. You can use the IDs in this data to do property queries to the Land Registry for title deeds, addresses etc. but I think this is a paid service.

Also, it's restricted to **freehold properties**, so there will be (sometimes large) gaps, even in the same street, for other types (e.g. Leasehold)